# Can't download or update

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

Every time I run `sudo apt-get install` or `sudo apt-get update` I get the following error message:

```
dpkg: irrecoverable fatal error, aborting: 
 files list file for package 'kde-runtime-data': Input/output error 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question and translate it to english. I suppose that `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` may help.

Comment: it did not work

Comment: What edit did you make to `/var/lib/dpkg/status` ? Specifically how many likes did you remove ? Did you run any other commands ? What is the output ?

Comment: i did not edit anything

Comment: *i did not edit anything* ?!? The answer posted above by @karel says to edit `/var/lib/dpkg/status` so... What did you do and what didn't work?